# How to find grails Environment in grails java source package

Tags: grails

Greetings of the day !

I have a requirement to check the environment in grails project Java source package. Please help me.
I am trying to use this code, but not getting success.

```
String envName = System.getProperty(Environment.DEVELOPMENT);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to get the current environment--

```
import grails.util.Environment;
...
Environment.getCurrent()
```

or test the environment --

```
Environment.getCurrent() == Environment.DEVELOPMENT
```